# Redis OM .NET Go Live date

Tags: redis

Redis OM .NET debuts a Beta feature (https://redis.io/docs/connect/clients/om-clients/stack-dotnet/).

Can cany one share details on its official launch timeline? Contemplating its inclusion in an upcoming April/March project launch and eager to assess its stability beforehand. Your insights would be invaluable!

I tried looking into the documentaiton and news sections of Redis